# My BottomNavigationBar icons goes outside of the screen

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am using `BottomNavigationBar` from [here](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx). I followed every instruction carefully and it works fine until I got this problem where icons pop out of the screen with too much of gap between them.

[image]

**Menu_items.xml**

```
    <menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Menu"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu"
            android:title="@string/nav_menu"
            android:visible="true"
            app:showAsAction="withText"/>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Deals"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/fire_deals_icon"
            android:title="@string/nav_deals"
            android:visible="true"
            app:showAsAction="withText"/>
    .
    .
    .
    </menu>
```

**MainMenu.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/main_menu_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/TextcolorforWhite"
            tools:context=".MainMenu">
   <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:id="@+id/main_nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items"/>
<View
        android:id="@+id/myProfileDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/main_nav"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/SettingsColor"/>

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="57dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/myProfileDivider">
</FrameLayout>
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: there is option "enableAnimation" to disable the animation and it wont expand after that

Comment: have you tried that ?

Comment: by Google recommendations, not so many items should be used, but according to the library it can support more than 4 items [view docs](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#). It can happen that the phone where you are using it has a very small screen and does not reach to show all the items.

Comment: can you post whole xml file

Comment: @abdul Animation is already disabled

Comment: Post your full xml

Comment: @TariqulIslam I did just now

Answer (score 0):

In `MainMenu.xml` (*in case of using constraintLayout, as the main parent layout, which is better to use*) change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="0"` and add these:

```
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

Also you may have to omit: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

Comment: Try to change the relativeLayout to a constraintLayout.
It will do so much better for you.
Otherwise, I can predict, you will have some other problems.
Any way, if you need that relativeLayout just use `align` attributes instead of `app:layout_constrain...`

Answer (score 0):

First remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from your `FrameLayout` Second in your `com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx` add below item:

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd = "true"
android:layout_alignParentStart = "true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: I think it's `android:layout_alignParentStart = "true"`
            `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` and I don't think removing bottom gone fix my problem

Comment: Yes it will be android:layout_alignParentStart . and in your framelayout align parent bottom is useless.

Answer (score 0):

See this [documentation](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#anatomy)

> Don’t use more than five destinations. For those cases, try tabs or a navigation drawer.

**Five destinations: Active destinations display an icon and text label. Inactive destinations use icons, and use text labels if space permits.**

*Did you check your icon size*

The recommended width is **24dp**

The recommended height is **24dp**